# e-commerce order system immutable orders

Tags: mysql, database-design, e-commerce

I use a classical schema to modelise an e-commerce system. See the image below :

[image: tables relation]

My question is : what happens when a product is removed from the DB and an order already have been made by a customer for this product ?
I use InnoDB so I have a constraint on OrderDetails.productCode (ON DELETE SET NULL) but that's not good beacause if the product is removed I can't retrieve the informations about this product when I display the orderDetails item.

What is the correct db pattern for that ? Make the products immutable ? I mean make them undeletable ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the product has any orders on it, prior to deleting, and if so, use a flag such as deleted = 1 to treat it as deleted.